# Migration from spring boot 2.1.9.RELEASE >> 2.7.18 closes my Listener and it did not before

Tags: spring-integration, spring-webflux, ibm-mq, java-21

I moved my project from

- java8 to java21
- spring boot 2.1.9.RELEASE >> 2.7.18 (and thus spring-integration-jms 5.1.8.RELEASE >> 5.5.20)

In my code I have a controller returning SSE (TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)

```
        return Flux.from(noticesUsersTopicJmsReactiveSource())
                .filter(m -> filterOutMyMessages(m, userName))
                .map(Message::getPayload);
```

The noticesUsersTopicJmsReactiveSource() is a @Bean that returns the reactive Publisher

```
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(noticesUsersTopicDefaultMessageListenerContainer()))
                .channel(MessageChannels.publishSubscribe())
                .toReactivePublisher();
```

And the noticesUsersTopicDefaultMessageListenerContainer

```
    @Bean
    public DefaultMessageListenerContainer noticesUsersTopicDefaultMessageListenerContainer() {
        DefaultMessageListenerContainer d = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
        d.setConnectionFactory(topicConnectionFactory);
        d.setPubSubDomain(true);
        d.setDestinationName(noticesUsersTopic);        
        return d;
    }
```

**In spring 2.1.9**
When a browser connects, he receives the messages from the topics. (connection 1)
When I refresh my browser, I create a second call to the controller. (connection 2)
When a message from the topic comes in

- tries to write to connection 1 -> it fails and closes that
- tries to write to connection 2 -> is returned to the browser

**in spring 2.7.18**
When a browser connects, he receives the messages from the topics. (connection 1)
When I refresh my browser, I create a second call to the controller. (connection 2)
When a message from the topic comes in

- tries to write to connection 2 -> is returned to the browser
- tries to write to connection 1 -> it fails and closes that, **but it also closes the messageListener**

(so nothing of the topic comes in anymore)

*ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener$GatewayDelegate  - stopped org.springframework.integration.jms.ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener$GatewayDelegate@23eb6d13
11:28:12 INFO  o.s.i.j.JmsMessageDrivenEndpoint  - stopped bean 'noticesUsersTopicJmsReactiveSource.jms:message-driven-channel-adapter#0'; defined in: 'class path resource [com/../configuration/NoticesUsersTopicConfiguration.class]'; from source: 'bean method noticesUsersTopicJmsReactiveSource'
*

What could have changed?

All we want is a publisher of the topic messages. When a browser connects het gets the info, and when he disconnects, the publisher is still 'alive' for the next browser interested in topic messages.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Been debugging both versions for a couple of days now, and loosing my mind :-)

Comment: Many could have changes since then. Unfortunately both of those versions are out of Open Source support. So, it is recommended to migrate to the latest Spring Boot.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. If I could, I would, but unfortunately currently I'm stuck to 2.x version. Any idea where I should look? ..; What I'm trying should just work as before right? Or has there been memory based decisions maybe that would make this new default behavior logic? Any idea/direction would be appreciated :-)

Comment: Please, share a simple project to let me to reproduce, debug and play with. So, I may give you some workaround.